# Dotnet server in ec2 and postgress RDS connection timeout issue

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a dotnet server in a AWS EC2 mechine that connect postgress RDS, after 1 hour if the system is not in use then the connection pool between EC2 and RDS getting timed out, i have set maxPoolSize in dontnet, and also set all idle time out and tcp idle timeout ine RDS to 24 hours

But still the connection pool is getting timeout out by 1 hour if no one using, why?

I have added 24 hours time out for tcp time out and idle session time out, and also in dotnet server i added max pool size to 100

Answer (score 0):

You have to think differently when working with AWS Services. What would probably work with connection pooling with non-cloud infrastructures highly likely won't work by simply just throwing this in the cloud and expecting everything to work.

There are various articles on how AWS RDS Connection Pooling works which can be found here;

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ConnectionPoolConfiguration.html

You probably need to be using the AWS RDS Proxy Service to get this working as you expect.